# python3 flask: get multiple values for key in json post request

Tags: python, json, flask

I have a simple existing python API using flask that submits a post request in the body, then calls and executes another python script:

testflask.py

```
import testlogicdf
import json 
from flask import Flask, json, request, Response
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/results", methods=['POST'])
def createResults():
  entry = request.get_json().get('entry', '')
  passcode = request.get_json().get('passcode', '')


  data = testlogicdf.test(entry, passcode)
  return Response(data, mimetype='application/json')    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True, host='localhost', port=8080, passthrough_errors=False)
```

script that gets called: testlogicdf.py

```
 import pandas as pd

def passcodeMapping(entry):
  result = ''
  entry = int(entry)
  if (entry in range(1000, 3000)):       
    result = 'UKNOWN'
  elif (entry in range(0, 100)):
    result = 'Success'
  elif (entry in range(200, 999)):
    result = 'Error'
  return result

def test(entry, passcode):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    testInput = zip(entry, passcode)
    for entry, passcode in testInput:
        result = passcodeMapping(entry)
        df = df.append({'Entry': entry, 'Passcode': passcode, 'Second Attempt': result}, ignore_index=True)
    response = df.to_json(orient='records')
    return response
```

To achieve these results:

```
 [
    {
        "Entry": 2442,
        "Passcode": "Restart",
        "Second Attempt": "UKNOWN"
    },
    {
        "Entry": 24,
        "Passcode": "Try Again",
        "Second Attempt": "Success"
    },
    {
        "Entry": 526,
        "Passcode": "Proceed",
        "Second Attempt": "Error"
    }
]
```

What I am trying to accomplish is instead of passing this in the request body:

```
{
"entry":[2442, 24, 526],
"passcode":["Restart", "Try Again", "Proceed"]
}
```

I want to pass this to the API

```
[{
    "entry": "2442",
    "passcode": "Restart"
}, {
    "entry": "24",
    "passcode": "Try Again"
}, {
    "entry": "526",
    "passcode": "Proceed"
}]
```

as this is more cleaner and self explanatory. However the issue I am having is when passing that request to my api, I am getting the error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'"

I've had no luck debugging why I'm not able to pass my request body in that format. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server is trying to get value given a key from the JSON. The JSON you're sending is a list, not a dictionary. You have to either change the JSON you send to be a dictionary and change the server accordingly, or change your server (`createResults()`) to interpret the JSON as a list and iterate through it.

If you want it to be a dict, you can do something like this:

`{
    1: {{"Password": "asdf"}, ...},
    2: {{"Password": "xzvx"}, ...},
...
}`

But a list makes more sense, in my opinion.